# Error in remapping bounding box of warped image on original image

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have this original image `img1` :
[image]
I'm doing perspective warping on it with a `3X3` matrix `H1` like this :

```
h1, w1 = img1.shape
img1_rectified = cv2.warpPerspective(img1, H1, (w1, h1))
```

`H1` is computed by some other processes and has value :

```
[[ 2.88731913e-01 -1.78739074e-01 -8.87051698e-01]
 [-2.02198538e-03  3.11652261e-01  1.97936568e+00]
 [-2.49183072e-05  8.35014802e-06  3.39583885e-01]]
```

Which gives me this warped image :
[image]

Now, we have a rectangle (taken from user by some other function) on the warped image with `stereo_bbox = [219, 321, 1005, 634]` as drawn below :

[image]

`stereo_bbox` is a bounding box with starting x co-ordinate, starting y co-ordinate, ending x co-ordinate and ending y co-ordinate, always in that order. I'm trying to plot the modified version of same bounding box on the original image `img1`. I've tried this :

```
tmpimg1 = deepcopy(img1)
fourpoints = [
    [[stereo_bbox[0], stereo_bbox[1]]],
    [[stereo_bbox[2], stereo_bbox[1]]],
    [[stereo_bbox[2], stereo_bbox[3]]],
    [[stereo_bbox[0], stereo_bbox[3]]],
]
stereo_bbox_mapped = cv2.transform(np.array(fourpoints), H1)
mapped_stereobbox_sq = stereo_bbox_mapped.squeeze().astype(int).tolist()
mapped_bbox = mapped_stereobbox_sq[0][0], mapped_stereobbox_sq[0][1], mapped_stereobbox_sq[2][0], mapped_stereobbox_sq[2][1]

cv2.rectangle(
    tmpimg1,
    (mapped_bbox[0], mapped_bbox[1]), 
    (mapped_bbox[2], mapped_bbox[3]), 
    (0, 0, 255), 
    3,
)
```

But this gives wrong rectangle on the original image like this :

[image]

I've even tried with the inverse of the matrix `H1` (as suggested in one of the comment), like this :

```
linalginvH1 = np.linalg.inv(H1)
stereo_bbox_mapped = cv2.transform(np.array(fourpoints), linalginvH1)
```

But it gives again wrong result, out of picture like this :

[image]

Expected result is not exact polygon of the object which is surrounded by the rectangle in the warped image, but the right representation of top left and bottom right corners of the actual rectangle in the original image `img1`.

What am I doing wrong?

> The midpoints of the rectangles are also drawn along with the rectangle on each images, but I haven't added that part of code as it can be derived right once the rectangle is right.

Comment: first of all, the box will not be a box anymore, so you must actually draw a polygon using all four points. -- second, make sure you use H correctly. to map backwards, you need to use the inverse of H.

Comment: `cv.transform` wants your input to be of shape `(-1,1,2)`. try reshaping your values to that.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Reshaping `fourpoints` to `(-1, 1, 2)` doesn't help. Checked with both `H1` matrix and inverse of it.